# Oracle Apex Faceted Search with range

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to add two input fields "from and to" into my faceted search as shown on this image:
[image]

How to achieve this? If I add two input fields they will be in separate groups. How to arrange them next to each other in one search group and how to make the work together to select a minimum and maximum of values?

Answer (score 0):

It's a built-in feature. On the particular facet, ensure that `Type = 'Range'` and  then toggle the "Manual Entry" switch to On (this is under Settings section of the Facet properties, just under "Select Multiple").

View image here:

[image]

Hope this helps!